# Executing a SELECT statement on a cast(text) column that has XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am trying to retrieve all values in the XML that contains defined values in the `WHERE` clause but I am only retrieving the first record and not the subsequent records in the IN operator. I am needing to the `CAST` a text column to XML and then retrieve the records but I am not able to make this work. Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Here is the XML:

```
<Payment>
    <CoverageCd>COLL</CoverageCd>
    <LossTypeCd>COLL</LossTypeCd>
    <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
    <LossPaymentAmt>14596</LossPaymentAmt>
</Payment>
<Payment>
    <CoverageCd>LIAB</CoverageCd>
    <LossTypeCd>PD</LossTypeCd>
    <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
    <LossPaymentAmt>3480</LossPaymentAmt>
</Payment>
```

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT  
    ad.AplusDataSysID,
    CAST(ad.xmlAplus AS XML).value('(/ISO/PassportSvcRs/Reports/Report/ReportData/ISO/PassportSvcRs/PassportInqRs/Match/Claim/Payment/LossTypeCd)[1]','varchar(max)') AS LossTypeCode 
FROM 
    [dbo].[AUT_Policy] p
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[IP_Policy] ip ON p.PolicySysID = ip.Aut_PolicyID
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[AUT_AplusData] ad ON ip.PolicySysID = ad.PolicySysID
WHERE 
    CAST(ad.xmlAplus AS XML).value('(/ISO/PassportSvcRs/Reports/Report/ReportData/ISO/PassportSvcRs/PassportInqRs/Match/Claim/Payment/LossTypeCd)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') IN ('BI','PD','COLL','COMP','PIP','UM','MEDPY','TOWL','RENT','OTHR');
```

Here is my SQL result:

[image]

Here is what the SQL result should look like:

[image]

Comment: Is it as simple as changing the AND to an OR?

Comment: Two questions. Why are you storing xml in a column with a datatype that is not xml? Why are you using the text datatype for anything? The text datatype has been deprecated for almost 15 years now.

Comment: Sean - I'm not sure WHY anyone would define an XML column to a TEXT.  Whoever designed the table did it that way and is no longer here.  This is what I have to work with unfortunately.

Comment: Your sample results don't make sense. You have two _different_ `AplusDataSysID` values, but the `where` clause requires `AplusDataSysID = 1450937`.

Comment: KeithL, someone had reformatted my code and included the line that I had removed.  Please review the WHERE clause and let me know how to get the SUBSEQUENT <LossTypeCd> value if you would.  Thanks!

Comment: HABO, someone had reformatted my code and include the AplusDataSysID = 1450937 that I had removed. Please review the CORRECTED WHERE clause.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that the XML [nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) method is what you need.

```sql
-- Sample data
DECLARE @AUT_AplusData TABLE (AplusDataSysID INT, xmlAplus TEXT);
INSERT @AUT_AplusData VALUES (1,
'<Payment>
    <CoverageCd>COLL</CoverageCd>
    <LossTypeCd>COLL</LossTypeCd>
    <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
    <LossPaymentAmt>14596</LossPaymentAmt>
</Payment>
<Payment>
    <CoverageCd>LIAB</CoverageCd>
    <LossTypeCd>PD</LossTypeCd>
    <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
    <LossPaymentAmt>3480</LossPaymentAmt>
</Payment>');


-- Solution
SELECT 
  AplusDataSysID = ad.AplusDataSysID, 
  LossTypeCd     = pay.loss.value('(LossTypeCd/text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)')
FROM        @AUT_AplusData                     AS ad
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CAST(ad.xmlAplus AS XML))) AS x(xmlAplus)
CROSS APPLY x.xmlAplus.nodes('/Payment')       AS pay(loss);
```

**Returns:**

```
AplusDataSysID    LossTypeCd
----------------  ---------------
1                 COLL
1                 PD
```

Comment: Alan, thank you so much for your help.  It's very much appreciated.